# How to manage Bootstrap 4 grids?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two side like `col-md-6` & `col-md-6` and I have six `images` inside left side and right side. I need only one `images` like given below code.

This is working fine but I need expand left six column in full width when right side image will not be available. How can I manage this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:yellow;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:orange;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:blue;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:red;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:lime;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:indianred;">img</div>
    </div>
      </div>
          <div class="col-6 p-0">
      <div class="col-12" style="background-color:green; height:48px;">img</div>
</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want like as given below code if right `col-md-6` will be not available:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2" style="background-color:yellow;">img</div>
      <div class="col-2" style="background-color:orange;">img</div>
      <div class="col-2" style="background-color:blue;">img</div>
      <div class="col-2" style="background-color:red;">img</div>
      <div class="col-2" style="background-color:lime;">img</div>
      <div class="col-2" style="background-color:indianred;">img</div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this with just CSS? I mean the obvious solution is to just alter your logic wherever you render you HTML and render it without the second column whenever the that image is unavailable.

Comment: Actually there is a condition in that right banner is not mandatory sometime it should be sometime not. thats the problem, not unable to understand how to manage it.

Comment: So when the right banner is not there, which part of the HTML will be missing? Just this `<div class="col-12" style="background-color:green; height:48px;">img</div>` or `img` or the entire column `<div class="col-6 p-0">...</div>`?

Comment: entire column `<div class="col-6 p-0">` will be conditional...

Comment: Oh in that case @kantbtrue answer is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `col-6` with `col`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:yellow;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:orange;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:blue;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:red;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:lime;">img</div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:indianred;">img</div>
    </div>
      </div>
          <div class="col p-0">
      <div class="col-12" style="background-color:green; height:48px;">img</div>
</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think he knows that. I could be wrong, but I think he is interested in how to do that dynamically after determining that the bigger image is unavailable.

Comment: It will work, even the bigger image area removed dynamically.